# MS Access Query Criteria - ConcatRelated unexpected results with dates as filter, not returning some records

Tags: concatenation, filtering, criteriaquery

I'm adding a summary report to a job planning access database.

To summarise a large amount of small jobs assigned to a person on a given day, I'm using Allen Browne's ConcatRelated [ConcatRelated](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html)to return a list of assets (SID) in a query.

I need to use 3 criteria in the Where section to filter the results:

1. Contract Number (CID)
2. Person the Job is assigned to (AssignedTo)
3. Date the job is assigned to be completed (Date)

The first two work perfectly, and the Date at first seemed to work - however for certain dates I've found it returns zero results, even though there are relevant records to return. E.g 31/08/23, 09/09/23, 13/09/23 all return correctly, but 1/9 to 8/9 and 10/9 to 12/09 doesn't return anything. (Database uses Sharepoint Lists for the tables, set to UK Date format dd/mm/yyyy). Other (non-concat based) queries using dates work fine so I don't think its the date setting of the site/Dbase - but open to suggestions if I may be missing something.

This is my Query Field:

```
SIDs: ConcatRelated("SID","ActiveJobs","[Contract] = " & [Contracts].[ID] & "AND [Assigned To] =" & [ActiveJobs].[Assigned To] & "AND [Date] =" & "#" & [ActiveJobs].[Date] & "#")
```

For the date filter I've tried a few things (for hours!) e.g. not using the #, using "" (couldn't find the right syntax to make this work) but just can't seem to find a working solution. I'm not great with filters so am reaching out for help!

I'm guessing I just don't have the syntax of *[Date] =" & "#" & [ActiveJobs].[Date] & "#"* correct. Any ideas?